# Python Tkinter Question: Getting It All To Fit In The Window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, layout, grid-layout

I'm working on a tkinter application where I have a window with several widgets placed using the grid geometry manager. I'm trying to adjust the width of the columns to make the layout more compact, but I'm having trouble achieving the desired look.

Fields are cut off in the window:
[image]

Code:

```
personal_info_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(ind_window, text="Client Information", padx=10, pady=10)
personal_info_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="nsew")

parent_info_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(ind_window, text="Primary Parent/Guardian Contact", padx=10, pady=10)
parent_info_frame.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="nsew")

parent_info2_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(ind_window, text="Auxilary Parent/Guardian Contact", padx=10, pady=10)
parent_info2_frame.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="nsew")

other_info_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(ind_window, text="Other Information", padx=10, pady=10)
other_info_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=0, pady=0, rowspan=2, sticky="nsew")

drug_treatment_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(ind_window, text="Drug Treatment (Skip if no treatment)", padx=10, pady=10)
drug_treatment_frame.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=0, pady=0, sticky="nsew")

button_frame = tkinter.Frame(ind_window, padx=5, pady=5)
button_frame.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=4, pady=20, sticky="nsew")

pad_x = 2
pad_y = 2

pp_gar02_state = tkinter.BooleanVar()
pp_gar02_checkbutton = tkinter.Checkbutton(parent_info2_frame, text="Refer to Parent Project", variable = pp_gar02_state)

par_gar02_label = tkinter.Label(parent_info2_frame, text="Full Name:")
par_gar02_label.grid(row=0, column=0, padx= pad_x, pady =pad_y, sticky="W")
par_gar02_entry = tkinter.Entry(parent_info2_frame, width = default_entry_width)
par_gar02_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="W")
par_gar02_rel_label = tkinter.Label(parent_info2_frame, text="Relationship:")
par_gar02_rel_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="W")
par_gar02_rel_combo = ttk.Combobox(parent_info2_frame, values=["Mother", "Father", "Grandmother", "Grandfather", "Aunt", "Uncle", "Agency Rep. (Add Org.)"], width = 20)
par_gar02_rel_combo.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="W")
par_gar02_org_label = tkinter.Label(parent_info2_frame, text="Organization:")
par_gar02_org_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="W")
par_gar02_org_entry = tkinter.Entry(parent_info2_frame)
par_gar02_org_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="W")
par_gar02_address_label = tkinter.Label(parent_info2_frame, text="Address:")
par_gar02_address_label.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="W")
par_gar02_address_entry = tkinter.Entry(parent_info2_frame)
par_gar02_address_entry.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="W")
par_gar02_email_label = tkinter.Label(parent_info2_frame, text="Email:")
par_gar02_email_label.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="W")
par_gar02_email_entry = tkinter.Entry(parent_info2_frame)
par_gar02_email_entry.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="W")
par_gar02_phone_label = tkinter.Label(parent_info2_frame, text="Phone:")
par_gar02_phone_label.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="W")
par_gar02_phone_entry = tkinter.Entry(parent_info2_frame)
par_gar02_phone_entry.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="W")
pp_gar02_checkbutton.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="W")
blank_label = tkinter.Label(parent_info2_frame, text="")
blank_label.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="W")
blank_label = tkinter.Label(parent_info2_frame, text="")
blank_label.grid(row=8, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="W")
```

How can I adjust the column widths in a `tkinter` grid layout to make the fields more narrow, while maintaining the overall look of the window?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

I was expecting the labels and fields to fit within the window.

I've attempted to set the `minsize` for each column using `columnconfigure`, but it doesn't seem to have the desired effect.

I've also tried adjusting the width attribute of the `Entry` and `Combobox` widgets, but the overall column width doesn't seem to change accordingly.

Comment: Add `columnspan=2` to `pp_gar02_checkbutton.grid(...)`.